# Message Passing Issue

Tags: c#

I'm in my second week of OOP, our tutor has given a messaging passing exercise to do, I'm having an error that I can't seem to resolve. The error is:

> Obj_Orientated_CD_MOVIE_Library.Movie' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Obj_Orientated_CD_MOVIE_Library.borrowCopy()'

which in turn has led to the subsequent error:

> Obj_Orientated_CD_MOVIE_Library.Movie.borrowCopy(Obj_Orientated_CD_MOVIE_Library.Student)': no suitable method found to override

I'm not sure if I've explained it correctly, here's the code.

```
abstract class Item
{
  protected int copies;
  protected int availCopies;
  protected string title;

  public Item(string newTitle, int newCopies, int newAvailCopies)
  {
      title = newTitle;
      copies = newCopies;
      availCopies = newAvailCopies;
  }

  public abstract void borrowCopy(Student objStudent);

  public abstract void returnCopy();

  public int Copies
  {
      get
      {
          return copies;
      }
      set
      {
          copies = value;
      }
  }

  public int AvailCopies
  {
      get
      {
          return availCopies;
      }
      set
      {
          availCopies = value;
      }
  }

  public string Title
  {
      get
      {
          return title;
      }
      set
      {
          title = value;
      }
  }
}


class Student
{
  public string date;
  public string returnDate;

  public Student(string newDate, string newReturnDate, string newTitle, int newCopies, int newAvailCopies)
      : base(newTitle, newCopies, newAvailCopies)
  {
      date = newDate;
      returnDate = newReturnDate;
  }
  public void borrowMovie(Movie objMovie)
  {
      objMovie.borrowCopy(this);
  }
  public void borrowCD(CD objCD)
  {
      objCD.borrowCopy(this);
  }
  public override void borrowCopy(Student objStudent)
  {
  }
  public override void returnCopy()
  {
  }
}

class Movie : Item
{
  public string runTime;

  public Movie(string newTitle, string newRunTime, int newCopies, int newAvailCopies)
      : base(newTitle, newCopies, newAvailCopies)
  {
      runTime = newRunTime;
  }
  public string Runtime
  {
      get
      {
          return runTime;
      }
      set
      {
          runTime = value;
      }
  }
  public override void returnCopy()
  {
      availCopies++;
      Console.Write("\nThank you for returning the Movie\n");
  }
  public override void borrowCopy(Student objStudent)
  {
      if (AvailCopies > 0)
      {
          AvailCopies--;
          Console.Write("Please refer to receipt for return date of the Movie\n");
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("\nThis Movie is not available at this time, please try again later");
      }
  }
}

class CD : Item
{
  public string band;

  public CD(string newTitle, string newBand, int newCopies, int newAvailCopies)
      : base(newTitle, newCopies, newAvailCopies)
  {
      band = newBand;
  }
  public string Band
  {
      get
      {
          return band;
      }
      set
      {
          band = value;
      }
  }
  public override void returnCopy()
  {
      availCopies++;
      Console.Write("\nThank you for returning the CD\n");
  }
  public override void borrowCopy(Student objStudent)
  {
      if (AvailCopies > 0)
      {
          AvailCopies--;
          Console.Write("Please refer to receipt for return date of the CD\n");
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("\nThis CD is not available at this time, please try again later");
      }
  }
}
```

Constructive criticism and help please.

Comment: @JamesGaunt is correct, you either need to update the signature of `Item` to include a `Student` argument, or ditch that argument from the `Movie` implementation of `borrowCopy`.

Comment: Could you or James give me an example of what it should look like? I'm a visual learner, once I see it how its suppose to look in code, I understand it better.

Comment: Take what you have, remove the `Student objStudent` from `borrowCopy()` in `Movie`, and it will work. From what you posted, you aren't even using that `Student` object in the method anyways.

Comment: I've updated my Student code in the original post, I'm receiving No overload for method 'borrowCopy' takes one argument. for both borrowMovie and borrowCD.

Comment: Why does `borrowCopy()` in `Movie` need a reference to a `Student`? I'm asking that to get you to think about your code organization, I suspect I know what that reason is but it isn't obvious from what you've shown.

Comment: We've basically been give the exercise to implement message passing into our code, "Association" I was given a small exercise leaflet and it just says that I need to add the borrowBook(Book objBook) mine is Movie because I just preferred to do my own class. Then within that method within the Student class, to input objBook.borrowCopy(this);

Comment: Then just update `Item` to include the `Student` argument and you'll be fine.

Comment: By the way - why is Student an Item? I think there are some fundamental OOP design issues to be considered here.  I understand this is a lesson of course, but the code would be easier to understand if the design was logical.  In OOP terms the relationship between Student and Item should probably be a has-a relationship, rather than an is-a relationship. If Students can take out multiple Items then potentially a Student has-multiple Items.

Comment: @JamesGaunt, I broke down and posted an answer and did address that specific issue. I did not delve into has-a/has-multiple line of discourse, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for details, here you go. Here's the stuff you need to change. The updated `Student` class:

```
//is a Student an Item? I think not
class Student 
{
   public string date;
   public string returnDate;

   public Student(string newDate, string newReturnDate)
   {
       date = newDate;
       returnDate = newReturnDate;
   }
   public void borrowMovie(Movie objMovie)
   {
       objMovie.borrowCopy(this);
   }
   public void borrowCD(CD objCD)
   {
       objCD.borrowCopy(this);
   }
}
```

Notice I've removed the inheritance of the `Item` abstract class here, a `Student` is not an `Item` (I challenge you to come up with circumstances under which you can "borrow" copies of a student, assuming we are talking about human students). I could see you wanting some other class fields here, like a name value (I'll come back to this later).

Then `Item` has two method signatures updated:

```
public abstract void borrowCopy(Student objStudent);

public abstract void returnCopy(Student objStudent);
```

Then, when you call `movie.borrowCopy(this);` from within a `Student`, you won't get any errors, and can utilize any methods or properties in `Student` from within that method. If you added a `Name` property in `Student`, you could modify your `Console.Writeline` in `borrowCopy()` to say "Joe Blow, please refer to receipt for return date of the Movie" by updating it like this: `Console.Write("{0}, please refer to receipt for return date of the Movie\n", student.Name);`

Comment: Fantastic, I removed the Inheritance and altered it just as you've shown and it's working correctly, thank you so much for this, seeing it in code has given me what I needed, the level of understanding as to why I need it in there, absolute frustration-saver.

Comment: I'm trying to add the name into the Console of Movies borrowCopy(Student objStudent) however, when I press dot, I do not get the option for name within the Intellisense.

Comment: I've fixed it, I was trying to use the instance Student instead of the objStudent.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be overriding borrowCopy incorrectly.  We'd need to see the code of Item, but the signature you are providing:

```
void borrowCopy(Student objStudent)
```

...is not the same as the signature of the abstract method in Item.

From the error it appears the method in Item doesn't have any parameters.

So you are getting the two errors, firstly you don't provide an implementation of borrowCopy with the required signature, and secondly you use the override keyword for a signature that doesn't exist on Item.

Try this:

```
    public override void borrowCopy()
    {
        if (AvailCopies > 0)
        {
            AvailCopies--;
            Console.Write("Please refer to receipt for return date of the Movie\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThis Movie is not available at this time, please try again later");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps type out exactly what I need to change and where, this is preventing me from carrying on with my work and is also very frustrating. I'm a visual learner, I learn better when I see the it typed syntax-wise.

Comment: That was my original code before we had to start the implementation of message passing, I need to introduce the Movie objMovie and Student objStudent into this.

Comment: But you aren't using Student in the method.  If you need it in the method then you need to change the signature of borrowCopy in Item to match that in your new code (i.e. to include the Student parameter). The signatures of borrowCopy in Item and Movie need to be the same.

Comment: I'm going to post my updated code now, I think I have it working, no errors but, could you please check it to make sure it's message passing correctly and my syntax is correct.

Comment: Well, if it compiles that's good. But you still don't use the Student object in the implementation of borrowCopy. So I'd suggest something is wrong, but the problem is in the design rather than the syntax. It's not clear what the design should be. Passing a 'message' just for the sake of passing it, and not using it, seems like a strange design objective.

Comment: I have been struggling with association for days now, do you have any useful links or could suggest help, I'm confused that when I make an object of the class, define its constructor value, I know I type the objects name first, after that, when I hit (dot) do I use the method of the first class then the object of the other class? My tutor has not gone to a great length of detail on how association works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'association' here?  I'd just work through some basic tutorials on C#, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx and if you get stuck on a specific point post on here.